# What are the pros and cons of using ErgoEmacs?

Tags: emacs, ergonomics

I've been trying to learn Emacs lately and really like it so far... except for some of the less familiar key bindings (copy/paste and arrow keys for instance). I've read that ErgoEmacs mode modifies some key bindings so that they are more ergonomic and easy to pick up.

What are the pros and cons of using this mode? All I can think of is it can be harder to follow online tutorials and it won't be on all default installs. Anything I'm leaving out?

Answer (score 4):

This is already asked and answered on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323630/should-i-start-out-learning-emacs-with-ergoemacs

Answer (score 2):

The big disadvantage is being lost if you ever have to use somebody else's emacs...

Comment: Emacs is implied to be customizable, so everybody's Emacs is different, and you will most likely be lost in someone's Emacs. So this doesn't count as a serious argument, i think.

Comment: Basic things like "save" and "undo" and "cancel command" etc etc are rarely customized. I've never had trouble with a colleague's emacs, but the basics are always where I expect them to be.